# como puedo retorar la ruta completa en un ciclo forearch php

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de recorrer un `foreach` que viene por una ruta `get` de .htaccess, pero estoy obteniendo el último elemento y necesito obtener el path completo. Por ejemplo:

```
localhost/file/folder1/folder/2/demo.php
```

Devuelve solo:

```
demo.php
```

Éste es mi código PHP:

```
$part = array_filter(explode('/', route));
$end_part = end($part);
$file = null;
if(isset($part) && $part[0]=="file" &&  (count($part)>1)){
  unset($part[0]);
  foreach ($part as $value) {
    if($end_part==$value){
      $file = $value;
    }else{
      $file = $value."/";
    }
  }

  echo $file;

}else{
  error_response(404);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Php dispone de una función propia para el tratamiento de urls. Se trata de parse_url. http://php.net/manual/es/function.parse-url.php.

En tu caso, puedes hacer:

$lista= parse_url($url);

Con esto tendrás un array asociativo con las distintas partes de tu URL. En tu caso te interesa la clave PATH.

$path= $lista[`path`];

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que concatenar el valor de $file:

```
foreach ($part as $value) {
    if($end_part==$value){
      $file .= $value;
    }else{
      $file .= $value."/";
    }
```